# Why doesn't a letter show up when enclosed in < and >?

Tags: bug, formatting

I've just discovered that the [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/540328/365490) I had given on EL&U was missing something. When I pressed the edit button, I saw that I had written a V and enclosed in **<** and **>** i.e.  **< v >** (without spaces) but it just wouldn't show up. It's not showing up here either ->   (press edit to see)

[image]

I had written `<v>` but when I submitted the answer, the 'v' didn't show up in the answer. It was fine back then. Is there something wrong with the formatting? Am I formatting it incorrectly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The system is interpreting `<v>` as an HTML tag, and therefore it's not shown. Not all HTML tags are supported, but e.g. `<b>`, to make things bold, works:

```
<b>test</b>
```

produces

**test**

Notice that the tags seem to have gone here as well, but in this case they *do* have an effect. For a list of supported tags, see [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange. This [may indeed be rather confusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85886/295232).

It *is* possible to use <v> in regular text, if you replace the opening `<` with its HTML entity `&lt;` (or `>` with `&gt;`).

Comment: Or simply escape it with a backslash: `\<b>` will display `<b>`.